# Destructor gets called when I call a simple function

Tags: c++, c++14

I made a simple program making a class and it's 3 objects. I overloaded =, +=, and << operators. The problem is that when i use = and += operators, the destructors get called after the execution of the function.

As far as I know, **destructors are called when an object goes out of scope or when the 'delete' operator is used**. But, in my case, it's none of the two. I looked into some other websites, like [the oficial C++ website](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors), but, I couldn't get the answer. Here's the code that I wrote.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Class
{
    int flag,name;
public:
    Class(int y,int z)
{
    flag=y;
    name=z;
}

    Class& operator=(Class);
    Class operator+=(Class);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,Class&);    

    ~Class()
{
    cout<<"Destroying "<<flag<<endl;
}
};

int main()
{
    Class C1(1,80),C2(2,90),C3(3,100);
    cout<<C1<<C2<<C3<<endl;
    C1=C2=C3;
    cout<<C1<<C2<<C3<<endl;
    C3=C1+=C2;
    cout<<C1<<C2<<C3<<endl;
    return 0;
}

Class& Class::operator=(Class x)
{
    name=x.name;
    return *this;
}

Class Class::operator+=(Class x)
{
    name+=x.name;
    return *this;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o,Class& c)
{
    o<<c.name;
    return o;
}
```

The output I'm getting is this:

```
8090100
Destroying 2
Destroying 3
100100100
Destroying 1
Destroying 2
200100200
Destroying 3
Destroying 2
Destroying 1
```

Destructors of C2,C3 and then C1,C2 are called in the process even when they're not out of scope. I tried this program by changing the function names and even changing the return type to 'void', but still, the destructors were called. I compiled this program in GCC-4.9.3.

I would appreciate any help on this topic, and do forgive me if my question is too silly.

Comment: I bet you assumed that `flag` had a unique value because you build three objects with different flags.  **wrong**, **wrong**, **wrong**!  The compiler can often create temporaries, that by default copies every field *including* "unique values".

Comment: The objects destroyed are not your C1, C2, C3 variables but rather their temporary copies. Add an explicit copy constructor and print a diagnostics from it. Also use some static counter and increment it in constructors to enumerate the objects – then you'll see which objects are destroyed and when.

Comment: Your `flag` idea is wrong.  Just change your output statement to this:  `cout<<"Destroying " << this << endl;`  -- then you will see that those objects being destroyed are ones you didn't take in consideration, namely the temporary objects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your operators take the argument by value, making a copy which will be destructed when the function ends.

If you don't want to create a copy, take the argument by const reference. As [interjay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189205/interjay) pointed out, `operator+=` should also return a reference rather than copying `*this`:

```
Class& operator=(const Class&);
Class& operator+=(const Class&);
```

Comment: `operator+=` should also return a reference to avoid creating another copy.

Answer (score 3):

```
Class& Class::operator=(Class x);

C1=C2=C3;
```

When you do `C2 = C3` notice that the `operator=` takes the right hand side by value, so a copy of `C3` gets created (`x`); its data is copied to `C2`'s. When the function `operator=` returns, the parameter `x` goes out of scope and destroyed. This happens twice: once for `C2=C3` and once for `C1=C2`, so you see both. This also explains the behaviour of `operator+=`.

If you want to avoid that take `x` by reference, as shown in Tartan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to `Class& operator=(Class);` and `Class operator+=(Class);` They take objects as parameters (not references). Thus, destroying those temp objects invokes the destructor.

Just noticed more comments above explaining this... :)